# How to pass a parameter through all activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

I am developing a mobile application where I need the user object to be available through all the activities and I don't want to send it using the Intent from each activity to the other.

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Create a contructor for all your Activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make that object '**public static**'.
Then access it in other activities like:

```
PreviousActivity.userobj
```

Answer (score 3):

If you could store it in:

- [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or
- [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

I think the SharedPreferences would be much simpler to implement. 
Here is an example, how you could create a static function, wich you can access from all your activities:

```
public class UserCreator
{
    public static User getUser(Context context)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Check if the user is already stored, if is, then simply get the data from
        //your SharedPreference object.

        boolean isValid = prefs.getBoolean("valid", false);

        if(isValid)
        {
            String userName = prefs.getString("username", "");
            String passWord = prefs.getString("password", "");
            ...
            return new User(userName, passWord,...); 
        }
        //If not, then store data
        else
        {
            //for example show a dialog here, where the user can log in.
            //when you have the data, then:

            if(...login successful...)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("username", "someusername");
                editor.putString("password", "somepassword");
                editor.putBoolean("valid", true);
                ...
                editor.commit();
            }
            // Now, if the login was successful, then you can recall this function,
            // and it will return a valid user object.
            // if it was not, then it will show the login-dialog again.
            return getUser(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And then from all your activites:

```
User user = UserCreator.getUser(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a class which extends `Application` class. And put global parameters there. Those parameters will be valid in application context.

Comment: and how do I get those parameters ?

Comment: if you going to use your own application object, then u also need to change your manifest. In manifest, you have to add android:name=".yourownapplicationclassname" tag in application declaration. And access mechanism will be: ((yourownapplicationclassname).getapplication().